# disable scrolling up past specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

How can I make it so that a viewer cannot scroll **up** (past a specific point)?

Making it so a viewer cannot scroll is easy with:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but that disables scrolling down too.

## Detailed description

what I want is some javascript/jquery code that will not allow scrolling up past a given parameter, while the viewer can still scroll up and down before that parameter is reached, but after it is reached they can only scroll up **as long as it's not scrolling up past the given parameter**

I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a physical point and say something like:

```
$(function() {
    var scrollPoint = 200;
    var scrolledPast = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint ? scrolledPast = true : '';
        $(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint && scrolledPast == true ? $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint) : '';
    }).scroll();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7wtw/)

Although the disabling of scrolling seems a bit counter-intuitive-- why not just hide stuff off the page itself?

Comment: I do agree with you, this does almost everything I want and seeing how it works, it's not as clean as I imagined it. My only issue with this is that browsers like chrome will remember scrolling position and then not start at the top. When I added code to make it always start at the top, it broke yours. But other than that, this does everything I asked! Thank you