# Disable scrolling up after certain point on page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, mousewheel

I have an intro div on a page that calculates the window height so it fills the window:

```
resizeWindow();
$(window).resize(resizeWindow);

function resizeWindow() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var bh = $(document).height();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    featureHeight = wh - 0;
    $('#intro').css({'height':featureHeight+'px'});
}
```

I'd like to set it so once the user scrolls past this div, scrolling back up to that intro div is disabled.

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Combined the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925332/disable-scrolling-up-past-specific-point) and this does the trick:

```
resizeWindow();
$(window).resize(resizeWindow);

function resizeWindow() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var bh = $(document).height();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    featureHeight = wh - 0;
    $('#intro').css({'height':featureHeight+'px'});
    var scrollPoint = featureHeight;
    var scrolledPast = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint ? scrolledPast = true : '';
        $(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint && scrolledPast == true ? $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint) : '';
    }).scroll();
}
```

Comment: Could you try to hide the div?

Comment: It needs to be positioned relatively within the content hierarchy so hiding it wont work.

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925332/disable-scrolling-up-past-specific-point

Comment: Thanks @Sudhir - that answered my question. Have edited question to reflect working function.

Comment: @Michael if you found a solution, instead of updating it in question, add it as an answer and accept it to mark the question as closed. otherwise it'll remain open forever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925332/disable-scrolling-up-past-specific-point) and this does the trick:

```
resizeWindow();
$(window).resize(resizeWindow);

function resizeWindow() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var bh = $(document).height();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    featureHeight = wh - 0;
    $('#intro').css({'height':featureHeight+'px'});
    var scrollPoint = featureHeight;
    var scrolledPast = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop() > scrollPoint ? scrolledPast = true : '';
        $(window).scrollTop() < scrollPoint && scrolledPast == true ? $(window).scrollTop(scrollPoint) : '';
    }).scroll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, give your div an ID -- for example dvid, and suppose the other div (which you want to detect scrolling after) has an ID otherdiv. Then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
             //reached the desired point -- validate here or whatever you want
        }
    });
});
```