# CSS absolute positioning of elements in page background respecting contents layout

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

I'm trying to have some elements of design positioned absolutely relative to the page's background but not affecting the page layout (scroll and page height must remain dependent only on the page's contents).

Let say, placing two squares `square1` and `square2`, potentially overflowing on the page's width and maybe below the page's contents.

I've played with the following HTML:

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="square1">
    </div>
     <div id="square2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
  <!-- main content goes here, can be arbitrary HTML -->
  <canvas height="1000px" width="10" style="background:red;"></canvas>
</main>
```

Both with attempts at CSS `position: absolute` of the squares inside a `position: relative` background div and `overflow: hidden` on the `inner` div ; but also playing with only margin-based positioning, I always end up with the "background" overflowing below the main content. Are there alternatives approach to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

To be more explicit, on this JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1ktfyna4/2/ I'm trying to have  the page stop scrolling at the bottom of the red line, while still showing the top of the yellow rectange.

Comment: Maybe this will help you [https://stackoverflow.com/q/24730262/5277533](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24730262/5277533).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a pure CSS solution ideally, although I'm not excluding adding some JS if I can't make it another way.

Answer (score 0):

I made it simply using `display: flex` on the outward-most container, with both the content div and background div inside.

See https://jsfiddle.net/m8pk45re/1/